# Test site redirect to original site with HTTPS on

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I have two MAGENTO 1.7 websites example.com and test.example.com. On test.example.com I do extension testing prior to live publishing on example.com. The problem is when I go to SETTING--> CONFIGURATION-->WEB---> change Secured and Unsecure Base url to https://test.example.com... my test site automatically redirect to original https://example.com website.

Basically I cannot turn on HTTPS on test website.... However I can use test website without SSL/ https, using standard HTTTP, such as http://test.example.com

I have wildcard ssl on example.com

Any suggestions how to turn on SSL on Test website?

Answer (score 0):

As per you description.

Lets check step by step.

1 . check SSL installation is correctly and working fine on server ?

2 . all your directory and files have correct permissions  as many time I also faced the redirect issue when permission not correct.

folllow the correct permission,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244596/what-permissions-are-needed-to-run-magento

3 . set the secure url as per the given tutorial like here https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm